# EditText: gravity="center_horizontal" isn't working

Tags: java, android

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? :)

I want to set **gravity** for my **EditText** to **center_horizontal**, but it doesn't work.

Thanks and have a nice day!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/something"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Something"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.
I have removed the margin of the edit text and changed the layout_height to match parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/something"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Something"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to center the EditText inside LinearLayout

Replace

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

With

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Also, you should remove your margins so it would be perfectly centered horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

hiii.. i have try your code  its work good,  set gravity for edittext to set Edittext text in horizontal center and its work fine.

if to try to set edit text view in center horizontal. add gravity ="horizontal_center" in linear layout

see this screen shot :

[image]

Comment: pls can you explain what you want to do